# Different dependencies for different flavors and build types in gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Suppose I have such build.gradle:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
        }
        flavor2 {
        }
    }
}
```

How do I specify different dependencies such as:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1DebugCompile ...
    flavor1ReleaseCompile ...
    flavor2DebugCompile ...
    flavor2ReleaseCompile ...
}
```

Gradle will generate errors such as: `Could not find method flavor1DebugCompile() for arguments ...`

Comment: It is correct. where is the issue?

Comment: The gradle says `Could not find method flavor1DebugCompile() for arguments ...`

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug.
try this:

```
def customDeps = [
    flavor1DebugCompile   : dependencies.project(path: ':yourproject', configuration: 'flavor1Debug'),
    flavor2DebugCompile   : dependencies.project(path: ':yourproject', configuration: 'flavor2Debug'),
    flavor1ReleaseCompile : dependencies.project(path: ':yourproject', configuration: 'flavor1Release'),
    flavor2ReleaseCompile : dependencies.project(path: ':yourproject', configuration: 'flavor2Release'),
]

configurations.all() { config ->
    Dependency d = customDeps.get(config.name)
    if (d != null) {
        config.dependencies.add(d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to print out all the configurations but there isn't any config named like `flavor1DebugCompile`. I could see only such configs: `flavor1Compile`, `flavor2Compile`, `debugCompile`, `releaseCompile` etc.